# The difference between & and && in R

Tags: r, vector, boolean, logical-operators

I have read

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html

and the difference between & and && doesn't make sense. For example :

```
> c(1, 2, 3) & c(1,2,3)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

According to the link this is expected behavior. It is doing an element-wise comparison of the two vectors.

So I test again...

```
> c(1, 2, 3) && c(1,2,3)
[1] TRUE
```

This also returns what was expected.

But then I change a value...

```
> c(1, 2, 3) && c(1,3,3)
[1] TRUE
```

Still expected because it short circuits on the first element.

```
> c(1, 2, 3) & c(1,3,3)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This however lost me. These two vectors should not be equal.

Comment: You have me lost at `c(1, 2, 3) & c(1,2,3)` Can you say what you think this is evaluating?

Comment: I've never seen `&` used in this way.  I don't think it means equals, that's what `==` is for.  This gives you the expected result: `c(1, 2, 3) == c(1,3,3)`.

Comment: Replace your vectors with things like `x <- c(TRUE, FALSE)` and `y <- c(FALSE, TRUE)` and `z <- c(TRUE, TRUE)` and play around with `x & y` and `x && z` and see if you can figure it out now

Comment: Though playing around it seems anything `!=` 0 is seen as `TRUE` and anything `== 0` is seen as `FALSE`.  So  `c(1, 2, 3) & c(1,3,0)` explains a bit more.

Comment: @TylerRinker Indeed this is a bad example and may be the whole reason I misunderstood it in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`&` is a logical operator so R coverts your quantities to logical values before comparison.  For numeric values any non-0 (and non-NA/Null/NaN stuff) gets the value TRUE and 0 gets FALSE.  So with that said things make quite a bit of sense

```
> as.logical(c(1,2,3))
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
> as.logical(c(1,3,3))
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
> as.logical(c(1,2,3)) & as.logical(c(1,2,3))
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
> as.logical(c(1,2,3)) & as.logical(c(1,3,3))
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 11):

Consider this, then it should be clear:

```
as.logical(c(0,1,2,3,4))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

So...

```
c(1,2,3) & c(1,3,3)
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

is equivalent to:

```
c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE) & c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
```

...which compares by element using `&` and returns `c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)`

For reference:

```
test <- c(NA,NaN,-Inf,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,2,Inf)
data.frame(test,as.logical(test))

#   test as.logical.test.
#1    NA               NA
#2   NaN               NA
#3  -Inf             TRUE
#4  -1.0             TRUE
#5  -0.5             TRUE
#6   0.0            FALSE
#7   0.5             TRUE
#8   1.0             TRUE
#9   2.0             TRUE
#10  Inf             TRUE
```

Comment: In particular, `&` is not checking that the vectors are equal when evaluated as `numeric`.

Answer (score 7):

The "&" operator is only an element -by-element logical AND when the vectors are of equal length. That why you should also expect this result:

```
 c(0,1,2,3,4) & 1
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  # due to argument recycling
```

Notice that it is not comparing numerical values but only after coercion to type "logical", and any non-zero value will be TRUE:

```
seq(0,1,by=.2) & -1
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

"&&" only compares the first element of its first argument to the first argument of the second and issues a warning (but not an error) if either are longer than a single element.

If you want to test for equality then use "==".

Comment: With the usual warnings about using `==` with floats.