# Populate multiconditional boolean R using vectors instead of for

Tags: r, for-loop, boolean, zoo

This is the latest in my series "How to avoid for loops in R."  I imagine at some point, I will get it.

Below is the code, for the sake of this example, just run it with Strikes = 530.  There is no need to test all the others and worry about the GetStrikesForDay function.

```
TargetStrikes <- function(data, StrikeIncrement=2.50)
{
  epsilon = 0.10

  Strikes = GetStrikesForDay(data, StrikeIncrement)

  for (i in Strikes)
  {
    AtStrike <- abs(data$Close - i) <= epsilon
    data <- cbind.zoo (data, AtStrike)
    colnames(data)[length(colnames(data))] <- i
  }

  return(data)

}
```

As it is written, AtStrikes works beautifully.  It contains all True/False for the condition specified, one for each row in data.  I would like to add another condition and it is failing.

```
AtStrike <- abs(data$Close - i) <= epsilon || data$High>=i && data$Low <=i
```

Atstrike now beomes a single value, False, and that's it.  I no longer get a nice list of booleans which is what I want.

I know I can loop through each row, but I'd like to avoid that.  What is the best way to do this?  Right now, I am getting nowhere with it.  I've tried all sorts of combinations and no luck.

9:38 should be true based on the High being above 530 and the Low being below or equal to 530

Here is the data,

```
                      Open   High    Low  Close
2014-03-07 09:35:00 530.33 530.91 530.25 530.36
2014-03-07 09:36:00 530.54 530.98 530.37 530.73
2014-03-07 09:37:00 530.61 531.33 530.60 531.18
2014-03-07 09:38:00 531.19 531.25 530.00 530.19
2014-03-07 09:39:00 530.30 530.30 529.31 529.78
2014-03-07 09:40:00 529.71 529.89 529.32 529.59
```

Here is how I would like it to look after running the loop/statement:

```
                      Open   High    Low  Close AtStrike
2014-03-07 09:35:00 530.33 530.91 530.25 530.36 FALSE
2014-03-07 09:36:00 530.54 530.98 530.37 530.73 FALSE
2014-03-07 09:37:00 530.61 531.33 530.60 531.18 FALSE
2014-03-07 09:38:00 531.19 531.25 530.00 530.19 TRUE
2014-03-07 09:39:00 530.30 530.30 529.31 529.78 FALSE
2014-03-07 09:40:00 529.71 529.89 529.32 529.59 FALSE
```

And for entry into R,

```
structure(c(530.33, 530.54, 530.61, 531.19, 530.3, 529.71, 530.91, 
530.98, 531.33, 531.25, 530.3, 529.89, 530.25, 530.37, 530.6, 
530, 529.31, 529.32, 530.36, 530.73, 531.18, 530.19, 529.78, 
529.59), .Dim = c(6L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", "High", 
"Low", "Close")), index = structure(c(1394202900, 1394202960, 
1394203020, 1394203080, 1394203140, 1394203200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), class = "zoo")
```

Comment: Hi -- a self-contained answer would start with `require(zoo)` and substitute your `Strikes = 530` thing... it looks like you're also some way from having a minimal example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Look into the difference between `&&` and `&`: `help("&")`.

Comment: And likewise `||` vs `|` on the same page Roland mentioned.

Comment: Thank you Frank & Roland.  It was the double ampersand and pipe symbols that were tripping me up.  Frank, also thank you for the post on creating reproducible data.  I keep trying to do that and miss the mark with some of the details like you caught in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The difference between & and && in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669289/the-difference-between-and-in-r)