# Using & in R (e.g 3 < (5 & 9) )

Tags: r, logical-operators

I am trying to learn R and understand how the `&` symbol works. I understand it to mean 'and'.

When I try `3 < (5 & 4)` I get `FALSE`? I was expecting `TRUE`. Am I using `&` the wrong way?

Comment: This might be of interest to you too, in light of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21669446/496803

Answer (score 6):

In R `TRUE` evaluates to the number `1` in your arithmetic expression, hence:

```
3 < (5 & 4)
3 < TRUE
3 < 1
```

which is `FALSE`

You can convince yourself that R treats `TRUE` as `1` with the following code snippet:

```
> x <- c(-3:3)
> x
[1] -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3
> x == TRUE
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: And initially it is essentially doing `as.logical(5)` and `as.logical(4)`, which both return `TRUE`

Comment: As @nograpes pointed out in his answer, you probably were intending to do `all(3 < c(4,5))` to do a logical comparison of `3 < 5` and `4 < 5`.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you meant by your statement was how we would say it in English "Is 3 less then 5 and 4?". But that is not what `3 < (5 & 4)` means. As explained in other answers, R tries to figure out what (5 & 4) means first, then tries to figure out what it means for 3 to be less than `TRUE`. I think what you wanted is something like:

```
(3 < 4) & (3 < 5)
```

Another way to say it would be:

```
all(3 < c(4,5))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
3 < c(4,5)
```

This way it will test for both 4 and 5.

The answer I get is:

```
TRUE TRUE
```